# Method for filtering out list using logical operators && ||

Tags: c#, methods, filter, where-clause, operator-keyword

I have a list of ads that I want to filter by. The ads have only one content rating of either: G, PG, PG13, or R. Right now, I have a method that can filter through the list if I specify exactly one content rating. For example, if I pass in "G" into my method, I get back items on the list with only "G" content rating.

If I were to supply two content ratings, like "G" and "PG", the method does not return anything because it is looking for ads with content ratings of "G" and "PG" and such ads are nonexistent because only one content rating is associated with each ad.

I want to rewrite my method so that if I pass in two content ratings, say "G" and "PG", it will return the list of ads that have either "G" or "PG".

This is the portion of my method that needs to be addressed:

```
adList = adList.Where(ad => ad.IsG == filter.ContentRatings.IsG
        && ad.IsPG == filter.ContentRatings.IsPG
        && ad.IsPG13 == filter.ContentRatings.IsPG13
        && ad.IsR == filter.ContentRatings.IsR);
```

edit: filter is a class, ad.IsPG and filter.ContentRatings.IsG (IsPG13, IsR, IsG) are boolean values. if you are wondering, this does not work.

```
adList = adList.Where(ad => ad.IsG == filter.ContentRatings.IsG
        || ad.IsPG == filter.ContentRatings.IsPG
        || ad.IsPG13 == filter.ContentRatings.IsPG13
        || ad.IsR == filter.ContentRatings.IsR);
```

Comment: Can you share more of your current method? Are the parameters just coming in as strings? How are the parameters being used in the part that you do provide?

Comment: Why not you make a try with `||` as you indicated in the title. and what is `filter` in this scenario? where it is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you check all of the values where you should only check ad values that the filter is set to true for.

Maybe some code will make it clearer:

```
adList = adList.Where(ad => 
           filter.ContentRatings.IsG && ad.IsG
        || filter.ContentRatings.IsPG && ad.IsPG
        || filter.ContentRatings.IsPG13 && ad.IsPG13
        || filter.ContentRatings.IsR && ad.IsR);
```

As far as I remember `&&` is evaluated before `||`

Comment: This works! This solution completely escaped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Then you should be using the or operator || rather than the && operator.  Using && checks to make sure that both the left and right operand are true.  In other words, your statement will only return values where all four conditions are true.